# hash misses in rte_hash_lookup_bulk_data in DPDK rte_hash library

Tags: c++, networking, hash, dpdk, dpdk-pmd

DPDK hash library offers bulk data lookups with  rte_hash_lookup_bulk and  rte_hash_lookup_bulk_data. The functions return a bitmask as an argument indicating the hash hits as 1 and miss as 0. I want to know if there are similar keys inside the bulk itself(which needs to be looked up), will they return as hits or misses in the bitmask?

As an example, imagine there are two instances of the same key in the bulk. But that key is not hashed yet. Will both keys will be returned as misses?

In my program, I insert the new key to the hash table when there is a miss(0) in the returned bitmask. But when the bulk has same key more than one time, above logic cannot be used if the lookup returns a miss(0) for each instance of that key in the bulk.

Comment: I think the question is a bit vague. What do you mean by "similar" data inside the bulk?

Comment: As an example, imagine there are two instances of the same key in the bulk. But that key is not hashed yet. Will both keys will be returned as misses?

Comment: Please update the DPDK version, based on the title `hash misses in rte_hash_lookup_bulk_data in DPDK rte_hash library`, but in the explanation `I want to know if there are similar keys inside the bulk itself(which needs to be looked up), will they return as hits or misses in the bitmask`. can you please rephrase and make it clear

Comment: When the bulk contains the same key more than one time (key is not in the hash table yet), does the lookup return hash miss(0) for each instance of that key? I added an example in the question. I think it clarifies what is the issue.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Yes. If you have the same key multiple times in the input and the key is not inserted into the table yet, then you will receive multiple misses as well.